# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.kai.chloe.Menu }

Tags: android, android-intent

No Activity found to handle Intent error? How it will resolve.

```
<activity android:name=".Menu"android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.kai.chloe.Menu" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

manifest file

```
 Intent intent=new Intent("com.example.kai.chloe.Menu");
 startActivity(intent);}
```

Login page

Comment: why don't use `new Intent(this, Menu.class)` ?

Comment: Agreed. Do not put an `<intent-filter>` on an activity unless you plan on other applications starting that activity on their own. Also, since there is a class in Android named `Menu`, please name your class something else. Otherwise, you are likely to have problems with class name references (e.g., imports).

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent startMenu = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
startActivity(startMenu);
```

I would do it like this and don't use a `<intent-filter>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Intent code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And the `<intent-filter>` tag you should put inside the `<activity>` tag.